# InfoPath form options does not contain Security and Trust

Tags: sharepoint, infopath

Why does my Info-path 2010 form not contain "Security and Trust" as showed on [this site](http://support.formotus.com/hc/en-us/articles/201042247-Dealing-with-InfoPath-trust-and-security-issues)

My screenshot

[image]

Vs The site

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken,  that form is a list form. I guess you are trying to customized a list form in InfoPath. Some features and controls are not available/supported when editing a List form

Comment: Yup, that was it. Thanks. I had to create a workflow to overcome the limitations of the list.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure if this is the correct answer, but I'm running Infopath 2013 and I have that option on my forms. Might be something worth trying.